# the memory usage of netty normal in this dump?

Tags: java, memory, netty

for 13K users I have the following memory dump. I will paste the top 7 consumers. Netty seems to consume too much memory. Is this normal ?

(Netty Version:3.2.7, implementing IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler,Total Memory Netty Memory Usage:2.5GB minimum )

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:      23086640      923465600  org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment
   2:      28649817      916794144  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync
   3:      23086640      554864352  [Lorg.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;
   4:        118907      275209504  [I
   5:       5184704      207388160  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment
   6:       5184704      130874832  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;
   7:       1442915      115433200  [Lorg.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment;
```

Comment: That does sound like a lot.  Are you sure all resources are cleaned when a user disconnects?

Comment: the only references that I am keeping is for Channel, ChannelGroup object. Should I do something special after user disconnects ? Because my User (keeps references for Channel, ChannelGroup istances) instance count is identical with the concurrent user count.

Comment: I would check whether you get this much memory usage after 13,000 user connect, but don't disconnect. Or you get this usage only after users disconnect and re-connect many times.

Comment: there may be misunderstanding: 4.4GB is the total memory usage. The numbers above indicates that Netty using 2.5GB minimum. By the way do i have to consider some facts while cleaning resources (special for netty) ?

Comment: I would test to see what the nature of the problem first.

Comment: its probably increases after disconnect and re-connects many times. I have not restarted server for about 4 days.

Comment: If that is the case, you have a resource leak. It is possible you have such a leak even if you are doing everything you are supposed to with netty.  I would try to reproduce the problem and see what memory is used after all the users have disconnected.  I assume you are only looking at live objects. ;)

Comment: dumped using this command :jmap -histo:live <pid>

Comment: could you make the dump somewhere avaible ? I would like to have a deeper look with mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the memory usage is not normal.

Here are some facts about Netty internal memory usage

- One channel has two `ReentrantLocks`, (one read lock,one write lock)
- Channel stores all channel references in a
  `org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap` internally, and automatically
  removes on close (This is to assign unique channel ids).
- ChannelGroup stores channel references in a `org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap` on add() and automatically removes on close.
- There will be one `ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry` per item stored in `org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ConcurrentHashMap`.

so you can calculate the expected memory usage, if your handlers are not leaking any references.

Comment: can i say that Channel objects are not released after disconnect

Comment: found a leak that is causing netty objects not to be garbage collected. currently heap size is only 200MB for 10K users. which seems to be good.